# Simple Web Application Tomcat 7.0.x 404 Error Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

Tomcat is up and running. LH:8080, is showing tomcat page. I just added a simple Dynamic web project to the tomcat.

contextroot: CarPool. CarPool is created in Wtpwebapp folder.
But LH:8080/CarPool is throwing 404 Error.

Killed one day on this. pls help me on this.

Java version: jdk 1.6
Eclipse: kepler
Tomcat: 7.0.x

Comment: what is the error in console, you might hit the wrong context root.also paste you web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Have you deployed you application to tomcat? Just take a look at your tomcat-home/webapps directory that whether /CarPool exists.

Answer (score 0):

> CarPool is created in Wtpwebapp folder. But LH:8080/CarPool is throwing 404 Error.

There can be multiple issues related to this. One of the most basic error must be any of the following

1. Incorrect context name
2. There is nothing mapped to the context root (slash '/') of the application.

Take a look into your deployment descriptor (WEB-INF/web.xml) file so to see what ( if anything ) is mapped to the slash ('/'). You will be looking for welcome-file-list and any servlet/JSP mapped to a url-patter as '/'.

Since you are getting a 404 when you are hitting the URL with for just the context root , then nothing is mapped on that url-pattern ( or non of the welcome-files are present ). So you will have to change the URL and hit a resource directly. Like any page (`http://you-server:8080/CarPool/some/path/to/file.html` or jsp or whatever) or any servlet (`http://you-server:8080/CarPool/ServletName`).